# Script cargado dinámicamente (mediante JS) no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, ajax, arduino

Estoy intentando diseñar una interfaz web para visualizar datos de `Arduino`.

La interfaz consta de la página principal `(index)` que únicamente contiene un `<i>"top bar menu"</i>`, y debajo un `<div id="contenido">` preparado para inyectar dinámicamente el contenido de distintas páginas.

Ya sé que para esto normalmente se usa `PHP`, pero al tratarse de un servidor muy básico (placa Arduino) no puedo usar `PHP` y lo hago con `JavaScript`.

El código que uso para inyectar el contenido de otras páginas es el siguiente:

```
function load_page(page) {

    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', page, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (this.readyState!==4) return;
        if (this.status!==200) return;
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML= this.responseText;
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Inserta la pagina bien. El problema es que las páginas que inserto, incluyen su propio código `JS`, y este código no se ejecuta.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.SO], evita editar el titulo solo para poner (Solucionado) esto no debe hacerse de esa forma, te invito a que veas el [tour], para dar por solucionado tu problema acepta la respuesta que lo resolvió. Saludos

Comment: @ÁlvaroHuerga recuerda agregar las actualizaciones o estatus de tu pregunta en la pregunta original, no agregues nuevos comentarios como respuestas. Puedes realizarlo al dar click en la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/91582/edit)

Comment: Hola Álvaro, consideraste usar [IFrames](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe)?

Answer (score 0):

Navegando un poco en la web me encotre con una pregunta similar a la tuya perteneciente a la comunidad de stackoverflow y a esto **XMLHttpRequest.responseType** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType

intenta hacer lo siguiente

```
function load_page(page) {

    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', page, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'text';
        xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
            if (this.readyState!==4) return;
            if (this.status!==200) return;
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML= this.responseText;
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar :S

Comment: intenta ahora :)

Comment: tampoco funciona :S